# How to programmatically define python wrapper functions that have the same (optional) parameters of the functions they wrap

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing, docstring

I find myself defining a number of wrapper functions, mainly to avoid modifying functions that come from packages (either standard as numpy or my own). I would like the wrapper to be understood by the interpreter as to have the same arguments as the functions it is wrapping. For instance I have a function to wrap

```py
def wrapped(opt=1):
     DoSomethingWithTheParameters(opt)
```

which I currently wrap with a dictionary based wrapper

```py
def wrapper(kwargs):
    return wrapped(**kwargs)
```

But this has the drawbacks:

1. The list of arguments of `wrapper` is unknown to the interpreter
2. The `docstring` of the wrapper is empty  and would be nice if it can be inherited from the wrapped function

Any way I can define wrappers programmatically so that they get the same arguments list as the functions they wrap? any chance they can also get the same docstring?

Comment: That's exactly what [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is for.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, this seems to do it, but the documentation has no example showing what I can achieve and despite some attempts I am not getting anything that does the trick. What would me a minimal code in which I can define a wrapper that knows all the arguments of the wrapped?